# pymongo: Add field containing a dict

Tags: python, pymongo

Right now my mongo document has normal key/value pairs in it.

I want to add a field (staff) that is a dict.  I can run this code, and it doesn't complain, but the users field does not show up when I find the object.  The object shows up as if it was never added.

```
staff = {'foo':{'name':'Jack S.', 'title':'Pirate'}, 'bar':{'name':'Abe', 'title':'Mate'}}
ships.update(
  {'_id': 1}, 
  {"$set": {'staff': staff},
  upsert=False
)
```

My _id is definitely correct because I can find on that ID and I get the result without staff just fine.

How can I add this field to my existing collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
ships.update(
  {'_id': 1}, 
  {"$set": {'staff': staff}},
  false,true
)
```

** you were missing closing bracket. also your staff variable doesnt seems to a correct dictionary.it looks like list of dict. please check .